# Adding binary numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, binary

Im getting the error "invalid operands to binary + (have int* and int*)" and i don't know why It is throwing me this error. how would I go about adding the array elements of the 2 arrays. note both arrays are the same size.

```
int* complement2_add(int* first_complement2[], int* second_compelment[], int size){
int count = 0,remainder = 0, carryover = 0;

int* cAdd = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));


for(count = size-1; count >= 0; count--){
    remainder = first_complement2[count] + second_compelment[count] + carryover;

    if(remainder == 1){
        cAdd[count] = 1;
        carryover = 0;
    }
    else if(remainder == 2){
        cAdd[count] = 0;
        carryover = 1;
    }
    else if(remainder == 3){
        cAdd[count] = 1;
        carryover = 1;
    }
    else if(remainder == 0){
        cAdd[count] =0;
        carryover = 0;
    }

}
if(carryover == 1){
    cAdd[count] = 1;
}
return cAdd;

}
```

Then I am calling the function in main like this.

```
    int* add1 = complement_2_add(complement2Array1, complement2Array2, j);
```

Complement2Array1 and Complement2Array2 are defined the same.

```
int* complement2Array1 = signed2complement2(signedIntArray1, j);
```

and signed2complement2 is defined as.

```
int* signed2complement2(int signed_binary[], int size){
  int i = 0;
  int* complemt2Array = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
  int flipflag = 0;
  for(i = size-1; i>=0;i-- ){
    if(flipflag == 0){
        complemt2Array[i] = signed_binary[i];
        if(signed_binary[i] == 1){
            flipflag = 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        complemt2Array[i] = signed_binary[i] == 0?1:0;
    }
  }
  return complemt2Array;
}
```

Comment: you use "array of array". so, "int* first_complement2[]" is wrong, it should be something like "int* first_complement2"

Comment: what function is supposed to do is add 2 "binary numbers" that are in the form of an array.

Comment: you can pass an array as "int * first_complement2" to this function. just change function signature to "int* complement2_add(int* first_complement2, int* second_compelment, int size)"

Comment: You also want to show us how `complement2_add()` is called, what is being passed into and how the latter is defined.

Comment: The "binary operand +" has little-to-nothing to do with the "binary numbers" in your title.

Comment: @alk I added more code to the post

Answer (score 1):

```
  remainder = first_complement2[count] + second_compelment[count] + carryover;
```

In this `first_complement2[count]` **,** `second_compelment[count]` both are integer pointers .

As both `first_complement` and `second_complement` are array of integer pointers.

You need to dereference them before adding -

```
remainder = (*first_complement2[count]) + (*second_compelment[count]) + carryover;
```

### EDIT

Didn't you got any warning or error for passing a `int *` to a function which expects array of integer pointer or `int **` ?

```
int* complement2Array1 = signed2complement2(signedIntArray1, j);    // it is an int *
```

`complement2Array1` and `complement2array2` has to be of type `int **` or to be array of `int pointers`.

Or simple as @alk Sir suggested use `int *` instead of `int **`.

Comment: Okay that stops the error from happening but when I use the function in the main method and try to assign its return value to a variable it gives me an error this is how I am assigning it
    
int* add1 = complement_2_add(complement2Array1,       complement2Array2, j);

Comment: @Thorx99 Now you got a different error . Please post calling function also with all declarations.

Comment: "*gives me an error*" is the most unusable error-report possible. @Thorx99

Comment: @ameyCU initialization makes pointer from integer without cast and implicit declaration of function.

Comment: So add the prototype for `complement2_add()` *before* it is used. @Thorx99

Comment: @Thorx99  You need add prototype of function to declare it before hand.

Comment: Nitpicking: The *function* needs to be declared *using* its prototype.

Comment: @alk I have the function declared above main but it still has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int* complement2_add(int* first_complement2[], int* second_compelment[], int size){
```

if equal to

```
int* complement2_add(int ** first_complement2, int ** second_compelment, int size){
```

which from the way you use `first_complement2` and `second_compelment` and the way you call `complement2_add()` is wrong.

It seems you wanted

```
int* complement2_add(int * first_complement2, int * second_compelment, int size){
```

---

Also add the prototype to it before it is used:

```
int* complement2_add(int * first_complement2, int * second_compelment, int size);

... somefunc(...)
{
  ...

   int* add1 = complement_2_add(complement2Array1, complement2Array2, j);

   ...
}

int* complement2_add(int* first_complement2, int* second_compelment, int size)
{
  int count = 0,remainder = 0, carryover = 0;
  ...
```